# VS .Net reference issue

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone explain why this code line works perfectly fine in a method in another class, but yet in the class I am working on VS says its reference is missing? Both have the Import statement for System.Web.Security

```
 Dim newUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(username)
```

Here is the error message

Error   1   Type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' in assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices'. Either a reference to 'System.Web.ApplicationServices' is missing from your project or the type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' is missing from assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices'.

Comment: Are both classes in the same project and targeting the same framework?

Comment: yes, both target .net 4.5 and are in same project

Comment: What happens if you explicitly use `System.Web.Security.MemberShipUser` and `System.Web.Membership.GetUser(username)`? See this post too http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770156. Maybe the class that works also has `import System.Web`.

Comment: Saem error stating that its reference has been forwarded to system.web.applicationservices, but the project already has that reference too. And adding that Import statement does nothing either

Comment: can you add the entire error message to your question? When you hover your cursor over the word membership each time it occurs does it show the same class?

Comment: added the error message above

Comment: @dinotom: Does the following help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2980964/87698

Comment: Heinzi, unfortunately no, I am properly targeting 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well like another prior question I had, I had to manually enter the add assembly line into the web.config file

```
 <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

*Reference* is not the same as `Import`.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx), the `Membership` class is located in `System.Web.dll`. Thus, you need to add `System.Web.dll` to your project references.

Comment: Presumably the two classes would have to be in different projects in that case otherwise it shouldn't work for either classes.

Comment: and if I go to add reference to try to re-add it, it says that System.Web is already referenced